# ImageView setColorFilter

Tags: ios, android-studio, kotlin

```
 val Cat_Image: ImageView

    Cat_Image = findViewById(R.id.Cat_Image)
    var mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wrong)
    Cat_Image.setOnClickListener {
        Cat_Image.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
        mp.start()
```

hello guys i'm trying to make kid app i wanna put 2 diffrent picture when use click right one it change green when false it change red but i wanna change color red and then back normal i dont wanna image stay red for ever can you help me to set image change only when clicked and back normal color?